# How do I remove previous extension<->Program affiliations programatically?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to write a batch file which ensures that when a user clicks on a .JNLP file, it opens using javaws.exe (located in program files/java/... you know the drill)

I have written the following batch file:

```
ASSOC .jnlp=JNLPFILE
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles% (x86)" (GOTO x86) ELSE (GOTO x64)
:x86
FTYPE JNLPFILE="%ProgramFiles% (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe" "%1"
goto:eof
:x64
FTYPE JNLPFILE="%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe" "%1"
```

I am testing this all in windows 7 64-bit.

This... doesn't work.   Well, that's not entirely accurate.   It modifies the registry correctly, and it adds .jnlp to windows list of Recommended programs to run.  It does exactly what it should.

But it doesn't solve my problem.   See, For testing, I went to Default Programs and associated .jnlp files with Notepad.   And when I try to open .Jnlp files, IT tries to open in notepad, even after my code has run.

If I do an open with on a .jnlp, it gives me  the option to open with Notepad or javaws.exe   If I've run my code with the ASSOC, it adds a SECOND option of javaws.exe

I've tried ASSOC .jnlp="" and FTYPE JNLPFILE=""  To try and clear notepad out, but had no luck.

How do I make my batch file blow away prior settings and assert its dominance on the machine?

EDIT:   Using the answers below, I have added a single command to the beginning of my batch file, which should take care of my problem and make things work correctly.

```
REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jnlp /f
```

Comment: Have you tried both `assoc` and `ftype`?  `assoc .jnlp=JNLPFILE` followed by `ftype JNLPFILE="...\javaws.exe" "%1"`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I tried, and it did add an association, however there is another association (notepad) that I seem unable to remove.

Comment: I am able to delete a file's associations by just `assoc .jnlp=`

Comment: The steps to recreate my problem in windows 7:
1. Go to start->Deafault Programs->Assosciate a file type or protocol with a specific program.
2. find .jnlp and choose Notepad as the default program.
3. Do a assoc .jnlp=
4. Try to open a .jnlp file.  It will open with notepad, even though there should be no file assosciation.

Comment: This is not a problem with assoc and ftype, but rather with windows explorer.  Explorer, keeps its own list of extensions for the open with feature. See `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jnlp\OpenWithList`

Comment: Oh.....   Of course it does.  That..  yes.   I should be able to fix this problem.   Thankyou.  You have solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Explorer keeps its own list of file extensions for the user.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

To remove programs from this list, delete the program entry from

> - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.‌​jnlp\OpenWithList
> - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jnlp\OpenWithProgIDs

and set the desired UserChoice Progid in

> - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jnlp\UserChoice

Also, note that the OpenWithList and OpenWithProgids can be set at multiple levels.

> - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.xyz\OpenWithList
> - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.xyz\OpenWithProgIDs
> - HKCR\.xyz\OpenWithList
> - HKCR\.xyz\OpenWithProgIDs
> - HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\FileType\OpenWithList